# by.cssContainingText in Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, protractor

In Protractor there is a handy [`by.cssContainingText` location strategy](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText) that would basically do two things - locate an element (or elements) by a CSS selector and check the element's text to contain a desired string. Sample:

```
var elm = element(by.cssContainingText('#myid .myclass', 'Some Text'));
expect(elm.isDisplayed()).toBe(true);
```

*How can this be done in Python/Selenium?*

Note that I am aware of the XPath way of checking the text. I'm interested specifically in using CSS selectors and checking the text of an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we look at the [`by.cssContainingText` implementation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/86fd56917f039efbff8e6f323f4d91fa8bc821a4/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L575), we can see that, first, it locates all elements by the CSS selector and then checks the text of the matched elements to contain the desired string.

We can mimic the same logic in Python to create our own custom locator:

```
def by_css_containing_text(driver, selector, text):
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(selector)
    return [element for element in elements 
            if text in (element.text or 
                        element.get_attribute("textContent") or 
                        element.get_attribute("innerText"))]

# usage
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

elements = by_css_containing_text(driver, '#myid .myclass', 'Some Text')
self.assertTrue(elements)
self.assertTrue(elements[0].is_displayed())
```

This is though not the exact same idea as in Protractor since we are not using `querySelectorAll` directly but making a CSS selector search through the Python/Selenium "find" function.

I'm also not sure if we have to check the `textContent` and the `innerText` attribute values - I feel like checking the "text" only would be sufficient enough in practice.

Comment: Did you work out a simpler method of implementing css:contains?  Sounds awfully complex for a simple css:contains text method.   //a[contains(text(), "Log Out")]  looks a lot neater as a simple a:contains('Log Out') sadly does not work.

Comment: Also how can you ask and answer a question at: answered Dec 30 '16 at 5:21?