# Understanding the cssContainingText locator functionality in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

I am currently in process of creating a framework using Protractor. I was trying to use `cssContainingText` locator given by the Protractor API. However, the locator failed giving an `invalidElement` exception, which seemed wierd to me.

The HTML of the page looks like this

```
     <tbody>
        <tr class="row2">
             <td class="action-checkbox">...</td>
             <th class="field-name">
                 <a href="some_link">someText</a>
             </th>
             <td class="field-slug">sometext</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr class="row3">
             <td class="action-checkbox">...</td>
             <th class="field-name">
                 <a href="some_link">someOtherText</a>
             </th>
             <td class="field-slug">someothertext</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row4">...</tr>
             <td class="action-checkbox">...</td>
             <th class="field-name">
                 <a href="some_link">someThirdText</a>
             </th>
             <td class="field-slug">somethirdtext</td>
        </tr>
```

I was trying to use the text `someText` using the following locator-

`element(by.cssContainingText('.field-name','someText'));`, which weirdly gives an `InvalidLocator` exception. When I use the following locator `element(by.cssContainingText('a','someText'))`, the code works perfectly fine.

As per what I understand from the explanation given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391028/by-csscontainingtext-in-python-selenium), and the Protractor implementation given [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/86fd56917f039efbff8e6f323f4d91fa8bc821a4/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L575), the `cssContainingText` first locates all the elements using the CSS Selector and then matches the required text.

So, it seems perfectly fine to me to use the `.field-name` class name for the CSS Selector and then match the desired string. However, this fails, which I am not able to understand. Inputs on this would be helpful.

Comment: Does it fail on all browsers? Or is there a specific browser? When I use the sourcecode from Protractor and inject in in this page and that look for `findByCssContainingText('.post-taglist', 'javascript')` it works, so it's strange that it's failing for you

Comment: Yes, it fails on all browsers. I have tried with Chrome Dev build 60+ and latest FF. And yes, I am too, wierded out, because I expected the locator to work

Comment: Try this in your dev console in Chrome. `window.document.querySelectorAll('.field-name')[0].textContent` or `window.document.querySelectorAll('.field-name')[0].innerText`. This is weird because I cannot reproduce this either when trying it out here: https://angular.github.io/protractor-cookbook/ng1/calculator/ when querying for `'.ng-scope'` or `'.ng-binding'`

Answer (score 3):

You can view and follow the code in GitHub, starting from the [API documentation of cssContainingText](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText).

It comes down to this way of search for content in [`clientsidescripts.js`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/clientsidescripts.js):

```
var elementText = element.textContent || element.innerText || '';

if (elementText.indexOf(searchText) > -1) {
    matches.push(element);
}
```

As `indexOf()` requires an exact match and your `th` element has neither `innerText` nor `textContent` (your `<a>` tag has), you don't get a result by using the `th` element.

As for differences between `textContent` and `innerText` let me refer to [this answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19032002/8683679) and [to this one as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21311670/8683679).

For your case:

```
[textContent]
someText
[/textContent]
[innerText]someText[/innerText]
```

```js
var properties = ['innerHTML', 'innerText', 'textContent', 'value'];

// Writes to textarea#output and console
function log(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
  var currValue = document.getElementById('output').value;
  document.getElementById('output').value = (currValue ? currValue + '\n' : '') + obj; 
}

// Logs property as [propName]value[/propertyName]
function logProperty(obj, property) {
  var value = obj[property];
  log('[' + property + ']'  +  value + '[/' + property + ']');
}

// Main
log('=============== ' + properties.join(' ') + ' ===============');
for (var i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
  logProperty(document.getElementById('test'), properties[i]);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  Warning: This element contains <code>code</code> and <strong>strong language</strong> and <a href="www.google.com">a Google link</a>.
</div>
<textarea id="output" rows="12" cols="80" style="font-family: monospace;"></textarea>
```